# How to achieve very slow slew rates in n-channel mosfets?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, slew-rate

I am designing a DC load with 20 parallel power MOSFETs. Each to carry 3 A at most. So, the power dissipation will not be a problem. I am trying to achieve as slow as 1 mA/µs current slew rate and this slew rate should be adjustable with a reasonable resolution. Is this possible? If so, how?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to control the actual current, or the resistance of the FET?  Also, how stable will the load current be vs resistance?

Comment: It's possible. If the peak power dissipation in your MOSFET is very high it may not like it much (eg. could fail). If this applies to your application, use a large safety factor with published SOA curves and test thoroughly.

Comment: There are numerous ways to achieve it; it would help if you could narrow down your question: what voltage and current rating, or range, do you need? What kind of conduction (voltage or current slew rate, some joint combination, etc.)?  Are you aware of the downsides of such features i.e. power dissipation? Will you have adequate components available (power dissipation and SOA) to handle it? If not, or if such design is prohibitively expensive, can a switching method be employed instead?  It might also help to discuss what you want this for: why should it ramp slowly, what's driven?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers. @Tim: To be more specific, I am designing a DC load with 20 parallel power mosfets. Each to carry 3 amps at most. So, the power dissipation will not be a problem. And yes, current slew rate is important for me. I am trying to achieve 1 mAmps/uS slew rate.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to slow down the turn on/off of the mosfet, you can simply connect a low pass filter (RC for example) between your control signal and your gate (nb: you might also try to just add the resistor and use the parasitic gate capacitance instead of C, but it will be more precise if you add a capacitor far greater than the parasitic one).

If you want to really control the gate voltage to make a turn on/off at the speed you want, you can consider connecting the gate to the output of a DAC (through a small resistor): then you can control the exact V_GS ramp you want from a micro-controller.

If this open-loop approach (+ optional calibration) is precise enough, then you are good. If not, you can also measure current through the mosfet, and do some closed loop control in the micro-controler: this way, you can hope to get precision in the order of 1% (or even lower with careful design and precise components).